# having multiple jar files with Main() function in the same java application project in NetBeans

Tags: java, program-entry-point, netbeans-9

I am creating a java application in netbeans that will require two executable jar files, one for the main application and the other for the application settings and config as states the application structure but i have a problem building the app in the netbeans ide, after each build the ide makes one jar file for the application and that for the settings is considered as a normal java class, please i don't understand this, how can i solve this problem.

[image: the application structure]

i want the Main.java and the portefeuille.java to run as separate jar files in the same project but the ide builds only the Main.java as a jar file.

Comment: There can only be one main class for a project. In your case you should create two projects. Or maybe even three: one library project for the classes that are used in both applications, one for the main application and one for the config application

Comment: You also could accomplish your goal by modifying the build script (usually `build.xml`, click on `Files` next to the `Projects` tab, it's right at the root of your project) to make the Jar files you want.  But that will require a bit of expertise and management, and simply creating two or three separate projects will probably be easier if you're not an expert on the command line tool set.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i will try your approach it will certainly be fine, guess i did not think of this before